# GNU Stow - is there any way to add file extensions to .stow-global-ignore or .stow-local-ignore files?

Tags: wildcards, stow

I want `stow` to ignore certain files, like `*.bak` and `*.tmp`, but I cannot seem to be able to add wildcards and get them to work.

I have tried:

```
*.bak
*.tmp
\*.bak
\*.tmp
```

I suppose wildcards are not supported? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ignore lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/manual/stow.html#Types-And-Syntax-Of-Ignore-Lists) contain [Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre), which are [ERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) with extra features.

```
.*\.(bak|tmp)
```

Note that the regular expression must match the whole file name (with or without the directory part — see the manual for details), not just a part of it (as is the case with the more common case of regular expression searches), so this does not match e.g. `foo.bakmore`, whereas `\.bak` would only match a file called exactly `.bak`.

Comment: Thanks. This does not seem to work with `.stow-global-ignore`, but this is a different issue and possibly a bug.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, but `.*\.env` is not matching with `foo.env`.